# How do you set the namespace of an XML element using Google Apps Script's XmlService?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I'm programmatically creating XML documents using Google Apps Script's [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service). However, I can't figure out how to add a namespace to an element. How do I use the XmlService API to add a namespace to an individual XML element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the namespace to an element when you create the element. See [XmlService.createElement(String, Namespace)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#createElement(String,Namespace)). However, Google Apps Script will raise an error if you attempt to pass a string literal for the second argument. What you need to do is call [XmlService.getNamespace(prefix, uri)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getNamespace(String,String)) method to create a Namespace object. You can then pass that Namespace object as the second arg.

```
// Create a namespace object.
ns = XmlService.getNamespace("xsi", 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

// Create an element.
var el = XmlService.createElement('devdef');

// Set the namespace of the element. 
el.setNamespace(ns);
```